# Does Python 3.6 sum() have `start=0` keyword argument?

Tags: python, sum, keyword-argument, positional-argument

It seems pretty basic, but as it relates to python language per se, I feel lost here. 
According to Python 3.6 documentation :

```
>>>help(sum)

...
sum(iterable, start=0, /)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers 
...
```

When I call: `sum([0,1,2], start=1)`, I am getting:

```
TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments
```

What's going on here?

Comment: No, it does not. A lot of these built in functions have positional only parameters that look like they could be keyword parameters

Comment: but if you do `sum([0,1,2], 1)` you will get `4`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/` in the prototype [is a convention that means that all arguments prior to it are positional only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/); they can't be passed by keyword. Functions defined in Python can't do this (at least, not without just accepting arguments into `*args` and manually unpacking the contents, though the linked PEP proposes doing allowing the syntax for Python level functions too), but since `sum` is a built-in implemented in C it can do this (it's actually doing the manual unpacking internally, but can advertise a more useful prototype), and define a default value much more easily. Not accepting arguments by keyword allows it to operate somewhat more efficiently than allowing for the possibility of keyword arguments.

Point is, the argument isn't *really* named `start`, so you can't pass it by name; you have to pass it positionally, e.g.:

```
sum([0,1,2], 1)
```

Comment: interesting. Is there a documentation about the `/` thing?

Comment: @DimaLituiev: No *good* documentation I can find, but it's mentioned [under item #10 in the Argument Clinic docs on converting your first function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html?highlight=positional-only#converting-your-first-function). The Argument Clinic is an initiative to simplify documenting and parsing function arguments for C level built-ins.

Comment: There is [an open bug to document them](https://bugs.python.org/issue21314), and it's also mentioned in [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/).